# jQuery don't know html element after insert via json

Tags: jquery, json

I load a lot of html code with json, but jQuery don't initialize the elements for the defined functions. jQuery .on don't work here.

```
$('body').on( 'click', '.cancel', function() {
    openCloseModalwin;
});
```

Why this don't work?

Comment: First of all, did you mean `openCloseModalwin()`?

Comment: Where is this code in relation to the start tag of the body element?

Comment: put code into jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`

Comment: openCloseModalwin() is a custom function that call by click the button, where comes via json.

Comment: When do you call this snippet code? BODY has to be available in DOM in order to bind event. See if that fix your issue: `$(document).on( 'click', '.cancel', function() {openCloseModalwin();});`

Comment: Hi Wolff, thanks this fix it. I have also test the document but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the click handler **after** the element is loaded into the DOM.

For example, this will work:

```
$(body).html("<button id='myButton'> Click Me </button>");

$("#myButton").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked!");
});
```

This will **NOT** work:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked!");
});

$(body).html("<button id='myButton'> Click Me </button>");
```

The reason being is that jQuery cant find the element to add the handler if it doesn't exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

after json load code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on( 'click', '.cancel', function() {
        openCloseModalwin;
    });
});
```